# Why does transparent stroke display with only half of width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-shape

I'm trying to use `<shape>` for displaying pressed state of the button. To do that, I use stroke with transparent color in normal state and colored one in pressed state:

*button.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

*button_pressed.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#0F0" />
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/size_medium" android:color="#F00" />

    <padding android:left="@dimen/size_medium" android:top="@dimen/size_medium" android:right="@dimen/size_medium"
        android:bottom="@dimen/size_medium" />
</shape>
```

*button_normal.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00F" />
    <stroke android:width="@dimen/size_medium" android:color="#0000" />
</shape>
```

And this is in my testing layout :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textAppearance="@null"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:enabled="true"/>
```

And that's how it looks like [image: half of stroke]

p.s. Extra question: why is padding used for both of states even if it is set only in pressed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stroke is split evenly on either side of the stroke path.  If there was a way to "peel back" the red outline on your second image, you'd see that the green box is the exact same size as the blue box in the first image.  And what you think is "padding" in the first image is actually part of your transparent stroke.

Try an experiment: make the stroke color translucent rather than transparent, and you'll be able to see how the stroke straddles halfway onto the shape.

It doesn't look as though there is any way in Shape XML to specify stroking to the inside or outside of the shape, so if that's really what you need, you might have to do your own `Canvas.draw()` calls in code.

Comment: Really strange for me. If there were any way to use something like `@dimen/my_size * 2` than okey, but.. Well, okey, Google. @kris larson, what can I do border button when it is pressed? Only hardcode two dimens with `my_size` and `my_size*2` values and maintain it on every change? Or is there any way to use something like negative stroke to expand it out of the buttons background like negative margin do in the layouts? p.s. Also still don't understand, why padding from one xml affects for selector.